# Server as both client and server in Java

Tags: java, server, concept

I am a newbie to server side operations. I am just wondering can a Java server be a server as well as client? 
Here is a scenario, Client-A connects to Server-A and requests some data from Server-A. Server-A don't have that data but it knows Server-B has that. Can Server-A pull that data from Server-B and push it to Client-A.

Any help to understand this concept would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course that is possible, and this is done in practice very often. Almost all web applications running on a server are at the same time the client for a database server running on another machine, for example.

Answer (score 1):

"Client" and "Server" are highly context-dependant. For example, your typical web server will probably be the "Server" on a http connection. On the other hand, it will probably be the "Client" for a database, and potentially other services (such as a web service, where it acts as the client on another http connection).

Comment: +1 and then there's the extreme case of the proxy which is both client and server for the same data, often doing nothing but hand it from one machine to another.

Comment: Okay that means it is possible. Now in my case , my Server B is media Server(red5). Is it possible that my Server A will act like client to Server B and pull media stream. If possible, to do so what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

In your example **Client A** is a `client` for **Server A** and **Server A** is a `client` of **Server B**.

To put in other words **Server A** acts as a `server` for **client A** and **Server B** acts as a `server` for **Server A**.

The terms server and client are used depending on the context. I hope I have not confused you.